# Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: delete from `jobs` where `id` = 26656)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using `php artisan queue:work --demon` to run jobs. But sometimes it gives this error.
How can I solve this problem for inbuilt laravel queue code?

In custom code I can handle it with `DB::transaction` but in core code how can I handle this?

Comment: How many workers are consuming that queue ?

Answer (score -1):

This happens when two processes or more are trying to write to the same database table at the exact same time. Solutions can be complicated. Deadlocks are usually an application problem most of the time can either be solved by:

1. changing the logic of your code (e.g. use transactions) or
2. retrying the operation

if use supervisor, change '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf' << numprocs=1